# Aurelia Webpack bundle not working with PhoneGap

Tags: webpack, aurelia, phonegap

I am looking for a way to make my Aurelia/ESNext/Webpack App work with PhoneGap (Android build).
Bundled files go into the "www" folder.
Looking at the inspector it seems that the webpack server is requesting some files from the wrong folder when running the app on a phone.

Any idea how to correctly configure Aurelia/Webpack to make it work?

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const project = require('./aurelia_project/aurelia.json');
const { AureliaPlugin, ModuleDependenciesPlugin } = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');
const { optimize: { CommonsChunkPlugin, UglifyJsPlugin }, ProvidePlugin } = require('webpack');

// config helpers:
const ensureArray = (config) => config && (Array.isArray(config) ? config : [config]) || [];
const when = (condition, config, negativeConfig) =>
  condition ? ensureArray(config) : ensureArray(negativeConfig);

// primary config:
const title = 'App';
const outDir = path.resolve(__dirname, project.platform.output);
const srcDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const nodeModulesDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
const baseUrl = '/';

const cssRules = [
  { loader: 'css-loader' },
];

module.exports = ({production, server, extractCss, coverage, platform} = {}) => ({
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    modules: [srcDir, 'node_modules'],
  },
  entry: {
    app: ['aurelia-bootstrapper'],
    vendor: ['bluebird'],
  },
  output: {
    path: outDir,
    publicPath: (platform || 'browser') === 'mobile' ? './' : baseUrl,
    filename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js' : '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.map' : '[name].[hash].bundle.map',
    chunkFilename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js' : '[name].[hash].chunk.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: outDir,
    // serve index.html for all 404 (required for push-state)
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  devtool: production ? 'nosources-source-map' : 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      // CSS required in JS/TS files should use the style-loader that auto-injects it into the website
      // only when the issuer is a .js/.ts file, so the loaders are not applied inside html templates
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        issuer: [{ not: [{ test: /\.html$/i }] }],
        use: extractCss ? ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: cssRules
        }) : ['style-loader', ...cssRules],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        issuer: [{ test: /\.html$/i }],
        // CSS required in templates cannot be extracted safely
        // because Aurelia would try to require it again in runtime
        use: cssRules
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        issuer: /\.[tj]s$/i
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        issuer: /\.html?$/i
      },
      { test: /\.html$/i, loader: 'html-loader' },
      { test: /\.js$/i, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: nodeModulesDir,
        options: coverage ? { sourceMap: 'inline', plugins: [ 'istanbul' ] } : {},
      },
      { test: /\.json$/i, loader: 'json-loader' },
      // use Bluebird as the global Promise implementation:
      { test: /[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]bluebird[\/\\].+\.js$/, loader: 'expose-loader?Promise' },
      // embed small images and fonts as Data Urls and larger ones as files:
      { test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|cur)$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 8192 } },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 10000, mimetype: 'application/font-woff2' } },
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 10000, mimetype: 'application/font-woff' } },
      // load these fonts normally, as files:
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|otf)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'file-loader' },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new AureliaPlugin(),
    new ProvidePlugin({
      'Promise': 'bluebird'
    }),
    new ModuleDependenciesPlugin({
      'aurelia-testing': [ './compile-spy', './view-spy' ]
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.ejs',
      metadata: {
        // available in index.ejs //
        title, server, baseUrl
      }
    }),
    ...when(extractCss, new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: production ? '[contenthash].css' : '[id].css',
      allChunks: true
    })),
    ...when(production, new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['common']
    })),
    ...when(true, new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: 'src/static', to: 'static', ignore: ['*.sass', '*.scss'] },
      { from: 'src/res', to: 'res' }
    ])),
    ...when(production, new UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true
    }))
  ]
});
```

Here is a screenshot from my inspector:
[Inspector screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3mnq.jpg)

Comment: can you share more details. For example, `webpack.config.js` to see the configuration? Also it would be helpful if you can also share the error you are receiving.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, please see the updated post.

Comment: Thank you. It appears to be the default `webpack` file. Can you tell me more about your directory structure? Where is `dist`  folder located?, `index.html` file? and `head` section from your html file to check if those files are referenced?

Comment: src
Source files are in the src

Comment: ok. Can you make sure `app.[chunk hash].bundle.js` & `vendor.[chunk hash].bundle.js` are referenced correctly where ever you are loading them?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that... I just know Webpack creates and manages them. The only reference is to the "webpack-dev-server.js" inside "index.ejs". If I look inside the "www" folder after doing the build I see all the compiled files (including those you asked for).

Comment: When looking at the inspector I see that index.html is loaded from "file:///android_asset/www/" while the others apparently are not.

Answer (score 2):

There's a sample project which demonstrates how to make Aurelia run on cordova (which is the underlying engine for PhoneGap): https://github.com/arjendeblok/aurelia-cordova-skeleton

A few key steps (from the readme):

### Prerequisites

- NodeJS
- Cordova
- Any platform-specific tooling like Android Studio

### Installation

After `npm install`

- `cordova platform add browser` for adding the browser platform to cordova.
- `cordova platform add android` for adding the android platform to cordova.

#### Running in development mode

After `npm build` (with development options):

- `cordova platform run browser` for running the app in the browser.
- `cordova platform run android` for running the app in Android.

#### Running in production mode

After `npm build` (with production options):

- `cordova platform build android`

### Files

In case the github repository disappears

#### `config.xml`

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

#### `webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { AureliaPlugin } = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('app/app.css');
const bundleOutputDir = './www';

module.exports = ({ prod, cordova } = {}) => {
    const isDevBuild = !prod;
    const isCordova = cordova || false;

    return [{
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
            modules: ['src', 'node_modules'] // .map(x => path.resolve(x))
        },
        entry: {
            'app': 'aurelia-bootstrapper'
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(bundleOutputDir),
            publicPath: '/',
            filename: 'app/app.js'
        },
        devServer: {
            contentBase: './www'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/i, include: /src/, use: 'ts-loader' },
                { test: /\.html$/i, use: 'html-loader' },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/i, use: isDevBuild ?
                        ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] :
                        extractCSS.extract('css-loader?minimize')
                },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|ttf|eot)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' },
                { test: /\.woff$/, use: "url-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
                { test: /\.woff2$/, use: "url-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000&mimetype=application/font-woff2" }
            ]
        },

        plugins: [
            extractCSS,
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({ IS_DEV_BUILD: JSON.stringify(isDevBuild), IS_CORDOVA: JSON.stringify(isCordova) }),
            new AureliaPlugin({ aureliaApp: 'main', dist: 'native-modules' }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: 'index.ejs',
                minify: prod ? {
                    removeComments: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true
                } : undefined,
                metadata: {
                   prod, cordova
                }
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]')  // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [])
    }];
};
```

#### `index.ejs`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
<% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.cordova) { %>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
<% } %>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <title>Hello Cordova</title>
    <!-- imported CSS are concatenated and added automatically -->
</head>
<body aurelia-app="main">
    <p>booting...</p>
<% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.cordova) { %>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<% } %>
    <!-- imported JS bundles are added automatically -->
</body>
</html>
```

#### `src/cordova-events.ts`

```js
export class CordovaEvents {
    waitForDeviceReady(): Promise<boolean> {
        let p = new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
                resolve(true);
            }, false);
        });
        return p;
    }
}
```

#### `src/main.ts`

```js
import { Aurelia, PLATFORM } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { CordovaEvents } from './cordova-events';

declare const IS_DEV_BUILD: boolean; // The value is supplied by Webpack during the build
declare const IS_CORDOVA: boolean; // The value is supplied by Webpack during the build
export async function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
    if (IS_CORDOVA) {
        const cordova = new CordovaEvents();
        await cordova.waitForDeviceReady();
    }

    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration();

    if (IS_DEV_BUILD) {
        aurelia.use.developmentLogging();
    }

    await aurelia.start();

    await aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('app'));
}
```